# WPF Datagrid Update Cell Value Button Click

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid that I have added two button columns to.  A plus and minus button, if you will.  What I want to do is when the user clicks the plus button another columns value increases by one.  Conversely, clicking the minus button subtracts one - if greater than 0.  So far, this is what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDtBS.jpg

It's the 'Standard Packs Needed' column that I would want this number to appear in.  I am relatively new to WPF so most of this type of stuff is confusing.  Anyway, here is my code:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" FontSize="15" CanUserAddRows="false" Margin="10,113,10,10" ColumnWidth="*" RowHeight="45" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" AlternatingRowBackground="#FF6E6E6E" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="#FF595A5B" Background="Transparent" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Black" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Black" CanUserReorderColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" >

        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF575757" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />

                <Style.Triggers>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF616161" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
            </Style>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="DodgerBlue"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Number" Binding="{Binding compOrderNumber}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Date" Binding="{Binding tstart, StringFormat=\{0:yyyy-MM-dd \}}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dataGridTextColumn" Header="Tool" Binding="{Binding tool}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parent Tool" Binding="{Binding parentTool}" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Component" Binding="{Binding component}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Color No." Binding="{Binding colorno}" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Material No." Binding="{Binding matno}" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding qty}" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Seq." Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding seq}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Press" Binding="{Binding press}" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LDR" Binding="{Binding LDR}" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Remaining" Visibility="hidden" Binding="{Binding remaining, StringFormat={}{0:n0}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight"  Binding="{Binding TotalWeight, StringFormat={}{0:n0}}" Visibility="Hidden"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                            <Button x:Name="myButton4" Background="Red" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Content="-" Foreground="White" Click="myButton4_Click"></Button>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                            <Button x:Name="myButton4" Background="Green" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Content="+" Foreground="White" Click="myButton4_Click"></Button>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Standard Pack"  Binding="{Binding stdPack}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Standard Packs Needed" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding needed}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-5"/>

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

and my code behind:

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim CmdString As String = String.Empty
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=10.0.0.54;Initial Catalog=Crib3LV;User ID=sa;Password=Jacob123!;Connect Timeout=200; pooling=true; Max Pool Size=200;")
        CmdString = " SELECT *, '1000' as [stdPack], '0' as needed FROM tblCurrentComponent WHERE press = 'D-PLR LH' AND printed = '1' "
        'CmdString = "SELECT DISTINCT orderNumber,  tstart, tool, colorno, matno, qty FROM tblSchedule WHERE press = '" & dataClass.press & "' ORDER BY tstart;"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(CmdString, con)
        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("Orders")
        sda.Fill(dt)
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
    End Using
    dataGrid.SelectedItem = Nothing


    dataGrid.Columns(9).Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    dataGrid.UnselectAll()


End Sub

Private Sub myButton4_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    'MsgBox("i fired")
    For Each rowView As DataRowView In dataGrid.SelectedItems
        If rowView IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim row As DataRow = rowView.Row
            gridind = dataGrid.SelectedIndex

            MsgBox(gridind & " " & row.ItemArray(4).ToString)
            dataGrid.Columns(4).IsReadOnly = False
            Dim row2 As DataRowView = DirectCast(Content.DataContext, DataRowView)

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

As you can see in the button click I know how to get some values, but I don't know how to set them.  What I plan on doing after is just looping through all the rows and inserting them into a SQL table.  I may be back here when that time comes.  Anyway, thank you for any help you can give me and thank you in advance for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to make your `DataTable` accessible to your click handler by making it a private field:

```
 Private myDataTable As DataTable
```

Then you can replace your `Dim dt As New DataTable("Orders")` with `myDataTable = New DataTable("Orders")`

You have given your two buttons the same name, so I would suggest that you fix that and rename your click handlers to something more meaningful, then do something like this:

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If dataGrid.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim currentCount As Integer = CInt(myDataTable.Rows(dataGrid.SelectedIndex)("needed"))
        myDataTable.Rows(dataGrid.SelectedIndex)("needed") = currentCount + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Then similar for the subtract:

```
Private Sub SubtractButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If dataGrid.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim currentCount As Integer = CInt(myDataTable.Rows(dataGrid.SelectedIndex)("needed"))
        If currentCount > 0 Then
            myDataTable.Rows(dataGrid.SelectedIndex)("needed") = currentCount - 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

As your `DataGrid` is bound to your `DataTable` any changes you make to the underlying table will update the grid.